# Azure IoT Edge module logs - Task upload logs failed because of error

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-iot-edge

I was following the experimental features of Built-in log pulls

https://github.com/Azure/iotedge/blob/master/doc/built-in-logs-pull.md

When I am trying to upload logs using the following payload from the azure portal(using Direct Method under each module)

**PAYLOAD**:

```
{
    "schemaVersion": "1.0",
    "sasUrl":"https://veeaiotcentralstorage.blob.core.windows.net/iotedgeruntimelogs/iotedgeruntimelogs.txt?sv=2019-02-02&st=2020-08-08T08%3A56%3A00Z&se=2020-08-14T08%3A56%3A00Z&sr=b&sp=rw&sig=xyz",
    "items": [
        {
            "id": "zigbee_template-arm64v8",
            "filter": {
                "tail": 10
            }
        }
    ],
    "encoding": "none", 
    "contentType": "text"
}
```

I am getting the error mentioned below after checking the task status

**ERROR**:

```
{"status":200,"payload":{"status":"Failed",
"message":"Task upload logs failed because of error Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.",
"correlationId":"b85002d8-d8f9-49d5-851d-9123a8d7d740"}}
```

Please let me know where I am having an issue

Comment: It could be that the system time is incorrect on your device. Can you check that the UTC time on your device isn't off by more than a few minutes?

Comment: I tried the same approach with my local Ubuntu System(as IoT edge device) and was sending direct method request from the portal. Still getting the same issue. My Ubuntu system time is in sync with network time

Answer (score 0):

Digging into the code some more, I noticed the UploadLogs implementation doesn't create a container, but rather a folder structure within the container that you supply. As far as I can tell, the casing restriction applies when creating a blob container, but there are no such restriction on creating folders within the container.

Please check the SAS URL that you supplied, or something on the storage end. Double check that your SAS URL is generated for a pre-existing blob container.